# bigQuery Google Cloud how to share dataset with other users? using python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a bigQuery dataset defined in Google Cloud with my userA account, and I want my colleague userB, who is a member of the same group, to be able to see the dataset that I have defined. Using the bq command-line interface, userB can see the project, but not the dataset. How can I share the dataset created by userA with userB using python script?

Answer (score 0):

An example using the Python Client Library. Adapted from [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views#assign_access_controls_to_the_dataset_containing_the_view) but adding a [`get_dataset`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.get_dataset) call to get the current ACL policy for already existing datasets:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

project_id = "PROJECT_ID"
dataset_id = "DATASET_NAME"
group_name= "google-group-name@google.com"
role = "READER"

client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)

dataset_info = client.get_dataset(client.dataset(dataset_id))

access_entries = dataset_info.access_entries
access_entries.append(
        bigquery.AccessEntry(role, "groupByEmail", group_name)
)

dataset_info.access_entries = access_entries
dataset_info = client.update_dataset(
    dataset_info, ['access_entries'])
```

Another way to do it is using the Google Python API Client and the [get](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.datasets.html#get) and [patch](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.datasets.html#patch) methods. First, we retrieve the existing dataset ACL, add the group as `READER` to the response and patch the dataset metadata:

```py
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from googleapiclient import discovery

project_id="PROJECT_ID"
dataset_id="DATASET_NAME"
group_name="google-group-name@google.com"
role="READER"    

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
bq = discovery.build("bigquery", "v2", credentials=credentials)

response = bq.datasets().get(projectId=project_id, datasetId=dataset_id).execute()
response['access'].append({u'role': u'{}'.format(role), u'groupByEmail': u'{}'.format(group_name)})

bq.datasets().patch(projectId=project_id, datasetId=dataset_id, body=response).execute()
```

Replace the `project_id`, `dataset_id`, `group_name` and `role` variables accordingly.

Versions used:

```sh
$ pip freeze | grep -E 'bigquery|api-python'
google-api-python-client==1.7.7
google-cloud-bigquery==1.8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you may run into is that you must give access at the data set level in BigQuery.  Depending on how you have setup user roles in cloud platform and BigQuery, you may need to give the service account direct access to the Bigquery data set.

To do this go into BigQuery, hover on your dataset and click the down arrow, select 'share data set'. A modal will open where you can then specify which email address's and service accounts to share the data set with and control their access rights.

Let me know if my instructions are too confusing and I'll upload some images showing exactly how to do this.

Good Luck!!